# Azure Data Lake Store exposed via OData

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Is it possible to expose an Azure Data Lake Store via OData? The main goal is consume this service in Salesforce (via Salesforce Connect).

If so, should it take place through Azure Data Factory?

**Update**

A little bit more of context:

We have historical data stored in Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) that we want to expose via OData (to be visualised in Salesforce via Salesforce Connect / External objects). After digging into the issue and potential solutions, we don't think ADLS is the right service to be used in this particular case. Instead, we'll might need to configure a Data Factory pipeline to copy the data we are interested in to a SQL Database and read the data from there via a simple ASP.Net application using Entity Data Model and WCF Data Services Entity Framework Provider (got some insights from [this website](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/accessing-sql-server-azure-database-lightning-connect.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OData has a connector for ADLS. However, given OData is basically a REST API, you could probably build an OData API over the existing ADLS REST APIs if they are not providing what you need. I am not sure how ADF would come into this picture?

Maybe it would be useful if you tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Michael! We do have historical data stored in ADLS that we want to expose via OData (to be visualised in Salesforce via Salesforce Connect / External objects). After digging into the issue a little bit more, I don't think ADLS is the right service to be used in this case. Instead, we'll might need to configure a Data Factory pipeline to copy the data we are interested in to a SQL Database and read the data from there. Any thoughts? Thanks again!